# Cannot upgrade pip on Windows

Tags: python, pip

I have Windows 10, Python 3.6 and want to upgrade pip. I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Acer Aspire E15>python -m pip install -U pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/b6/9cfa56b4081ad13874b0c6f96af8ce16cfbc1cb06bedf8e9164ce5551ec1/pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 538, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.1.dist-info\\description.rst' -> 'C:\\Users\\ACERAS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-y05m24ex-uninstall\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.1.dist-info\\description.rst'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 553, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.1.dist-info\\description.rst'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I do not know what more details to add. Can you help me find a way to upgrade the pip?

Comment: Are you running pip as admin? Check also permissions to directory `c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib\` sometimes it can be related with windows permissions issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error installing python 3.5 on Win 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990671/error-installing-python-3-5-on-win-10)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+upgrade+pip+PermissionError+WinError+5+Access+is+denied

Answer (score 1):

I believe the culprit is `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\...`.
Please, launch the command prompt as administrator or edit permissions of the python36-32 folder.

Duplicate of
[Python 3.5 pip install not working on Windows 7 - PermissionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35962193/python-3-5-pip-install-not-working-on-windows-7-permissionerror)

Comment: Yes, that was the reason. I changed the permissions for the folder and it worked.